# How can I run chromedriver on repl.it

Tags: python, selenium, replit

I basically want to use selenium on repl.it, but  don't know how to do that. I tried installing chromedriver into repl.it but I still get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/dictionaryBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 71, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1704, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'chromedriver'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "/home/runner/dictionaryBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "/home/runner/dictionaryBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 90, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/runner/dictionaryBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home
```

This is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://youtube.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try forking this Repl, it has working Selenium that you can use: [Advanced Selenium Options](https://replit.com/@LuisAFK/Advanced-Selenium-Options?v=1)